# What is the grammatical term for the word for someone who does something?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the name for the type of word that describes a ‘doer’ of the activity?  For instance, someone who takes photos is called a photographer, someone who sculpts is a sculpter, someone who robs is a robber, someone who runs from the police is a runner, someone who hides for three days is a wanted fugitive but also a hider.

What do you call those ‘-er’ words?  Kind of similar in ways to demonyms but not quite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called ***agent nouns***.

> A noun denoting someone or something that performs the action of a verb, usually ending in *-er* or *-or,* e.g. worker, accelerator.
>
> — [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agent_noun)